# Why only one public class per Java file?

Tags: java, language-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why only 1 public class in Java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578490/why-only-1-public-class-in-java-file)

Why does the Java language put a restriction that there has to be only one public class in a source file?

Comment: Please use the search feature before posting. Putting *your exact title* into the search field returns the answer as the first element!