# defining 2 public classes in single java file error

Tags: java

I try to define two classes with public access modifier.
But i got an error that the classes should be defined in respective java files.

my question is Why cant we have two public classes in one java class file?

i understood the error i just want to know , why cant we do it ? i mean the reason behind it

Thanks

Comment: Because that is how Java has been defined. If it did allow two public classes and both had main methods, which would be *the* main method?

Comment: Here is a link that explains it well IMO            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578490/why-only-1-public-class-in-java-file?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Josh that explains it.

Comment: we can have 2 public class in one file if the second class is a inner class `public class test1 {  
   public class tes2 {  
       ...  
   }  
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could explain why in a very simple way:

> Because if you did, the name of the java file wouldn't be the same as
>   the class name.

However, be sure to understand that is valid:

```
public Car{
 public Motor{

 }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578490/why-only-1-public-class-in-java-file?rq=1) you can read more about it.

You can read more about it in this interesting [oracle forum](https://forums.oracle.com/message/8966663)
discussion.

Hope it helps.