# Two default access classes in one .java file

Tags: java, class

I was trying to include two different `public` classes in one `.java` file but that did not run, and searching on stackoverflow gave me the answer that two top level classes cannot be in one `.java` file.

But the same class with `default` access run smoothly, Why is it so?

Comment: you can't create 2 files? create an inner/nested class maybe?

Comment: I can do that, but I wanted to know what exactly is happening with the compiler why does it let default access class pass and not public classes.

Comment: you might want to check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578490/why-only-1-public-class-in-java-file

Comment: Fully qualified name (file path based) is required to access public classes, because they can be accessed from anywhere. Whereas package-private classes are visible inside the package and don't need to be imported. I don't have a reference to support this, hence not posting it as an answer.

Comment: thanks @arjayosma but that does not talk about two default classes residing in one .java file

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6, particularly the conditions in the bullet list.

Comment: thanks @Kartik, that's actually what I was expecting.